# XPath Find full HTML element ID from partial ID

Tags: xpath

I am looking to write an XPath query to return the full element ID from a partial ID that I have constructed.  Does anyone know how I could do this?  From the following HTML (I have cut this down to remove work specific content) I am looking to extract f41_txtResponse from putting f41_txt into my query.

```
<input id="f41_txtResponse" class="GTTextField BGLQSTextField2 txtResponse"  value="asdasdadfgasdfg" name="f41_txtResponse" title="" tabindex="21"/>
```

Cheers

Comment: what do you meant by "full element ID"? can you provide an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas Jung I have been able to figure this out.  If I use:

```
//*[contains(./@id, 'f41_txt')]/@id
```

This will return just the ID I am looking for.

Comment: Be aware that this can fail. You might want to use `//*[starts-with(@id, 'f41_txt')]/@id` instead.

Answer (score 34):

You can use contains to select the element:

```
//*[contains(@id, 'f41_txt')]
```

Comment: With the way we are generating the webpage this is retrieving everything where I am just looking for the element ID.

Comment: //*[contains(@id, 'f41_txt')] will select a list of tags you have to iterate over it and select the id attribute for each of them. You can use count(//*[contains(@id, 'f41_txt')]) to get the total number.

Comment: Thats not the best way to do this.  I have answered my own question though with the help of you answer.

Comment: praise the lord, thanks to thomas jung i remembered that you always need the @ sign to find atrributes. duh.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to not use numbers from Id , when you are composing xpath's using partial id. Those number reprezent DINAMIC elements. And dinamic elements change over the next deploys / releases in the System Under Test.The pourpose is to UNIQUE identify elements.
 Using this may be a better option or something like this, yo got the idea:
//input[contains(@id, '_txtResponse')]/@id

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me like below

```
//*[contains(./@id, 'f41_txt')]
```